# Create an empty HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

Is it possible to create  HashSets with fixed capacities? Specifically one of zero and one of one. I have other HashSets which are convenient and that is the reason I am not using a list or something.

Comment: `new HashSet(1,1.0f)`---but that won't *limit* the capacity.

Comment: The idea is to limit it. I know that a singleton HashSet is weird but is it possible?

Comment: How about `java.util.Collections.singleton(T)`?

Comment: Along with `Collections.emptySet()`.

Comment: ok but how would you combine Collections with HashSets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend HashSet:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MyHashSet<Key> extends HashSet<Key> {

    private int limit;

    public MyHashSet(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public boolean add(Key key) {
        if (!contains(key) && size() == limit) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Limit exceeded.");
        } else {
            return super.add(key);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Integer> set = new MyHashSet<Integer>(1);
        set.add(0);
        set.add(1);  // IndexOutOfBoundsException
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted? It works fine. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Well, if you think it works fine, can you upvote and/or accept?

Comment: It will throw exception but value will be added to the set.